# Can't change location of global npm packages to $HOME

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, path

I am trying to follow along with this [Beginner's Guide to NPM](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/) and having trouble in the "Changing the Location of Global Packages" section. The goal in this section is to alter the location to which global Node packages are installed from root to $HOME/.node_modules_global.

Everything seems to work until I need to add `.node_modules_global/bin` to my $PATH environment variable, so that I can run global packages from the command line.

After including the following command to my .bash_profile file in $HOME...

```
export PATH="$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH"
```

... I don't see the updated local path when running `which npm`.

Pictures of my previous output and my .bash_profile where I export the PATH: [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD2Ox.png), [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOTWP.jpg)

To clarify, I'm expecting the output of `which npm` to output `/Users/mlongoria/.node_modules_global/bin/npm` instead of `/usr/local/bin/npm` since I included the export PATH statement in my .bash_profile located in my /Users/mlongoria/ directory. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm running OSX Catalina if it matters.

Comment: $HOME ,this envarmnemtal variable having path that

Answer (score 0):

can you make sure `npm` is in your global npm/bin?

you can try `ls $HOME/.npm_global` and verify?

if you want to move npm there, you can install npm again by `npm install npm -g`, this will use the global npm folder and then after that, it will be picked up (try closing session and open new tab)